# I am getting Beams Authentication Token Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, pusher

I am trying to authenticate with beams, but I am getting this error

```
Optional(PushNotifications.TokenProviderError.error("[PushNotifications] - Error when fetching token: error(\"[PushNotifications] - BeamsTokenProvider: Error while parsing the token.\")"))
```

Here is the code, please help

```
    let userId = UserManager.sharedInstance.userTokenModel?.userId ?? 0
let tokenProvider = BeamsTokenProvider(authURL: "\(base)api/pusher/beams-auth") { () -> AuthData in
    let sessionToken = UserManager.sharedInstance.userTokenModel?.token ?? ""
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer" + "\(sessionToken)"]
    let queryParams: [String: String] = ["user_id":"\(userId)"]
    return AuthData(headers: headers, queryParams: queryParams)
}
pushNotifications.setUserId("\(userId)", tokenProvider: tokenProvider, completion: { error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error.debugDescription)
        return
    }
    print("Successfully authenticated with Pusher Beams")
})
```

Comment: What is the response from your auth endpoint?

Comment: Does `headers` seems correct to you when set?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing all the headers required for fetching the token from your auth endpoint. Try parsing your GET request in https://reqbin.com/curl and see the response.
I had gone through the same issue, but the problem was due to incomplete headers required by the pusher auth endpoint. So I did the same and it helped!